# Criando Scaffold's para plugins no Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

Como faço para cria um `Scaffold` em um `plugin` do REDMINE?

Answer (score 1):

Basta criar um projeto `rails` independente com `Scaffold` e, em seguida, copiar `models / views / controllers` em seu plugin do Redmine!

Encontrei essa resposta nesse [link](http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/10503).

Comment: Resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: Deyel eu fiz este procedimento, mas não está funcionando. Já modifiquei todos os parâmetros de routes mas nada.